# Dynamic form in XAML using c# viewModel .net maui

Tags: forms, xaml, dynamic, maui

Creating a form for a user to do in XAML is not that difficult, however creating an ,,Edit-Mode" in which user can create his own form that he will submit is a little more challanging. Long story short - I can'f figure out how can I achieve the effect of an edit mode. The idea is that in the edit mode user chooses from drop down menu which elements he would like to have in his form and then saves it which navigates back to initial form (written in XAML) which now has the elements that the user chose in edit-mode.

I already have the button in XAML,

`<Button Command="{Binding EditCommand}" Text="Log in" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="20" HorizontalOptions="Center"></Button>`

but I have no idea how can I use ViewModel to modify the XAML form and add different entry types like normal entry, radiobutton, select with options etc basicly unlimited amount of times since user can add as many fields to the form as he wishes.

To add input elements to the XAML form I would need to modify the code in the file accordingly to what user chooses, but is it even possible from the ViewModel/C# level?

Answer (score 0):

The MVVM pattern is all about separation of concerns. That means that all things regarding visual is taking care of by the View. So if you want visual things to happen when you press the edit button you should consider keeping the logic in the View. However, if you need to involve business logic or the model, ie accessing data or saving settings, you go to the ViewModel. The ViewModel is ignorant of the view and its state. So try to make sure what it is you want to do.

Read [Data binding and MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/fundamentals/mvvm) and
[Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/mvvm) for more a better understanding of the MVVM